# How do I translate this VB.NET assignment to C#?

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

I usually program in VB.NET, but am trying to use C#.

In VB.NET, if `form1` has a `toolStripButton1` and in `UserControl` I usually write like this:

```
Dim first As New form1
first.toolStripButton1.enable = False
```

But in C#, I try:

```
private void MyNameMethod() {
    Form1 first = new Form1();
    first. ???????
```

but it doesn't work. How do I translate the above VB.NET code? I can not select `toolStripButton1`.

Comment: What is the exact C# code you're trying? And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: where have you defined the private void Function, in Form1.cs ? than this.toolStripButton1.enable will run. if you have defined the function in another control than you have to pass the Form1 object to the function. see below my answer.

Comment: no. I put private void function in UserControl.But May I upload pictures?

Comment: sure ... are you trying to access from a UserControl to Form ?

Comment: yes..so like this. when I called that UserContol, toolStripButton1 disable. Ok I will upload that pic

Comment: sorry I was not allowed to upload the pic Because I have yet to post 10 reputation

Comment: or I may ask for your email? I will send my program and also the code

Comment: See my answer, i've changed it, it may help.

Comment: If you're still stuck, then try answering my questions: What is the exact C# code you're trying? And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Chech the answer as true please which one you have used.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `toolStripButton1` is actually on `Form1` and set to `public`.

Comment: still can not, please help me guys.

Comment: Does `toolStripButton1` exist?

Comment: yess, but if I called this UserControl. toolStripButton1 disable

Answer (score 0):

Open Form1.Designer.cs [it is default class, may find easily from solution window, under Form1]

At the end of Form1.Designer.cs Controls are listed (as private Controls), change your control to public which you want to access.

Than on your UserControl's cs file add this codes:

```
private Form1 myForm;
public void AssignForm(Form1 _myForm)
{
    myForm = _myForm
}

private void AccessControl()
{
    myForm.myButton.Enable = ! myForm.myButton.Enable;
}
```

Open your Form1.cs file and you AssignForm function so that your UserControl may access your main Form. Put this code in your Form1-Constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     myUserControl1.AssignForm(this);
}
```

This is one of the ways to access to Form1 controls in an easy way.

Comment: sorry I was wrong writing

should be first, but it does not work as well

Comment: aha ... ops i will sleep now, tomorrow i will check some codes on VB and compare with C# if there is not any answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
first.toolStripButton1.enable = false;
```

The instance is `first`, `form1` is the name of the class.

Comment: You seem to be missing a semicolon.

Comment: sorry I was wrong writing should be first, but it does not work as well